# VirtualBox crashes when launching Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox

Whenever I launch Ubuntu in VirtualBox my computer just freezes and I have to restart it completely.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you have enough RAM memory? Please provide which version of Ubuntu you are running as guest, and what as host.

Comment: Please provide more information! Machine specs, kernel version, etc.

Answer (score -1):

It's to abstract to tell something specific. It depends on many things, Host OS that you run Virtual box (is it a latests version?), which version and architecture of Ubuntu are you trying to boot up. It also can be an issue with Virtual box settings. Also  did you check the file it self (ubuntu-somthing-somthing.iso) maybe file is download with errors, it happens some times (check sha1sum of the file or md5sum).

Comment: You are right, but that didn't answer the question. Please use comments if the question needs further clarification.

Comment: i typed uname -a command in terminal and this are the stats...

4.13.0-36 generic #40~16.04.1-ubuntu 
x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

i definatly know thet file isnt corrupted (or has any errors) i tryed uninstalling and reinstalling virtualbox, but it dosnt help 

i have 8GB (7.7) of ram and intel core i7-4510U CPU 2.00GHz x2
hardrive 1TB